# Django/Python assertRaises with message check

Tags: python, django, validation, unit-testing

I am relatively new to Python and want to use a `assertRaises` test to check for a `ValidationError`, which works ok. However, I have many `ValidationError`s and I want to make sure the right one is returned. I figured I could pass something into `assertRaises` but it doesn't look like I can, so I figured I would just do an `assertTrue` and check the exception message. However, I don't know how to access it. Is this even a good way to approach this issue? thanks.

```
class DailyEntriesTests(TestCase):
def test_cant_have_ip_and_user(self):
    u = createUser(False)
    de = createDailyEntry(u, "1.1.1.1", 1)
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as cm:
        de.full_clean()

    # this line bombs - message doesn't exist. I also tried "error_code" like I saw in the documentation, but that doesn't work
    print(cm.exception.message)

    self.assertTrue(cm.exception.message.contains("Both"))
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can just use [`assertRaisesRegexp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp).

```
with self.assertRaisesRegexp(ValidationError, "Both"):
    de.full_clean()
```

When you use it as a context manager the 2nd argument is a regular expression to search through the exception's string representation.

Comment: I just feel sorry for myself that this post is from 2014 and I never knew about this until now 

Answer (score 30):

Since the question is related to Django, you could also use the `assertRaisesMessage` context manager when inheriting from django's TestCase.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class ExceptionTest(TestCase):

    def test_call_raises_exception_with_custom_message(self):
        with self.assertRaisesMessage(Exception, 'My custom message!'):
            call_that_causes_exception()
```

---

**Note:** The [`assertRaisesMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#assertions) manager does an `in` lookup on the exceptions message: Say your exception raises *"My custom message!"*, asserting for *"custom message"* passes. Bear this in mind especially if you have multiple (custom) exceptions with similar messages.

(E.g. two different exceptions raising *"My custom message! Further details..."* and *"My custom message! No details."* would both pass an assert for *"My custom message!"*).

Answer (score 17):

Nowadays you can use `assertRaises` as [a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). This way you can capture the exception and inspect it later.

```
with self.assertRaises(SomeException) as cm:
    do_something()

the_exception = cm.exception
self.assertEqual(the_exception.error_code, 3)
```

Comment: this gave me the following error: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: I just tested and it is working fine with `CPython 3.6.4`

Comment: If you want to test the message, you can do something like: `self.assertEqual('{}'.format(cm.exception), 'I expected this message')`